# FileHelpers columns headers

Tags: filehelpers

Simple question as i cannot find it anywhere. How to set custom column names for each column? I tried to use this: `<FieldOrder(1), FieldTitle("Name")]>` but it says `FieldTitle` not existing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will just use the name of the field.

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
class Product
{
    // Must specify FieldOrder too
    [FieldOrder(1)]
    public string Name;
    [FieldOrder(2)]
    public string Description;
    [FieldOrder(3)]
    public string Size;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var engine = new FileHelperEngine<Product>();
        engine.HeaderText = engine.GetFileHeader();

        var products = new Product[] { new Product() { Name = "Product", Description = "Some details", Size = "Large"} };
        var productRecords = engine.WriteString(products);

        Console.WriteLine(productRecords);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Name,Description,Size 
Product,Some details,Large
```

If you need something different, you can just do

```
engine.HeaderText = "whatever,whatever,whatever";
```

Output:

```
whatever,whatever,whatever 
Product,Some details,Large
```

Comment: i already knew that way, but is there any column attribute instead of this approach?

Comment: No there is no built-in attribute for specifying the friendly name of the column. It will just use the field name.

Comment: ok thx for answer, can you look also at my second question here?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39526558/filehelpers-optional-columns