# FileHelpers optional columns

Tags: vb.net, filehelpers

I have static numbers of columns which my program will fill by data let's say 3. However at the end there could be additionally diffrent number of columns for pictures paths. At the moment i cannot say how many there will be as information will be comming from db so will be diffrent numbers of them. Question is how should i prepapre my class for that purpose? As you see below i declare 3 static columns but i have troubles how to do it for unknown number of pictures columns. Should i add 100 of them and mark as Optional or there is other way?

```
 <FieldOrder(1)>
    <FieldQuoted(QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted)>
    Public KategorieLevel3_5 As String

    <FieldOrder(2)>
    <FieldQuoted(QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted)>
    Public KategorieLevel4_5 As String

    <FieldOrder(3)>
    <FieldQuoted(QuoteMode.AlwaysQuoted)>
    Public KategorieLevel5_5 As String

    <FieldOptional>
    <FieldOrder(4)>
    Public Pic_1 As String

...
    <FieldOptional>
    <FieldOrder(100)>
    Public Pic_100 As String
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an array field.

```
<FieldOrder(4)>
Public Pic_1 As String()
```

If there could be zero pics, then you can also mark the property as optional.

```
<FieldOptional>
<FieldOrder(4)>
Public Pic_1 As String()
```

You can even set the minimum/maximum number of values in the array:

```
<FieldOrder(4)>
<FieldArrayLength(2, 8)>
Public Pic_1 As String()
```

Comment: what about my   engine.HeaderText = "Artikelnummer, Vater-Art.Nr., Variation 1, Variationswert 1" i cannot specify names for it here as i will be not knowing how many there will be so i could do like this:   engine.HeaderText = "Artikelnummer, Vater-Art.Nr., Variation 1, Variationswert 1, pic1, pic2, pic3...

Comment: I don't think there's an easy solution for the header. What if you're exporting 1000 lines and only the last one has 100 pics? You need to process all the lines before you can set the header.

Comment: so you mean either two options are possible - set up staticly e.g 20 pics as max then i can define columns and header staic way or set headertext after i recognize how many pics there is?